# Longtable, landscape in tufte-latex

Tags: longtable, landscape, tufte

I am using `tufte-latex` to write a document. I want to include a table which has many columns and rows in the document. For this purpose I am using `longtable` and `landscape` environments to produce the desired result. But what is happening is that since `tufte-latex` uses margin space on right had side for notes, figures and tables, in case of a longtable this space is not utilised. Since I am using `landscape` mode it appears there is a lot of white space at the bottom of the page. And the text overflows to the next page, even when there is space on the same page. Somehow the the margin space is not being used by the table. Please see the attached image to see what I mean. [image: Longtable and Landscape in tufte-latex]

Is there any way in which the entire width of the page can be used for the landscaped table?

A minimum working example is appended below:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\small
     \begin{longtable}{@{}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{5cm}p{4cm}p{5cm}}
\caption{Survey data from a  Mathematics textbook.}
\label{tba-math-5}\\

\hline
\textbf{Chapter}&\textbf{Page}&\textbf{Figure
  No.}&\textbf{Caption}&\textbf{Legend}&\textbf{Graph}&\textbf{Description}&\textbf{Data} &\textbf{Comments}\\

\hline

\endfirsthead
\hline

\textbf{Chapter}&\textbf{Page}&\textbf{Figure No.}&\textbf{Caption}&  \textbf{Legend}&\textbf{Graph}&\textbf{Description}&\textbf{Data}    &\textbf{Comments} \\

\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{9}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot

12&159&NA&NA&Yes&Bar Graph&Bar graph in a primitive form, tally
used for     counting and also as a legend. Investigative
questions to be answered     by looking at the chart.&Number of
different     favourite pet animals of children in form of a
table.&This is a good     introduction to bar charts, where number
count in form     of tally marks is used for counting and hence as
a measure of     height of a particular variable. \\
12&161&NA&NA&Yes&Bar Graph&Bar graph in a primitive form, tally
used for     counting and also as a legend. Investigative
questions to be answered     by looking at the chart.&Number of
different     vehicles passing a street in form of a table.&Follow
up from the     previous task. Here also number count in form of
tally marks is used for counting and hence as a measure of height
of a particular variable. The     follow up task asks students to
collect data about     trees in their colony and make a tally-bar
chart for the     data. \\
12&163&NA&NA&Yes&Pie Chart&Pie chart introduced as a Chapati chart
and     numbers to be matched on pie chart from table. It also
asks them investigative questions to be answered using such a
chart.&Number of children who     help most in house work in form
of     table.&This activity introduces students to pie charts. The
follow up task     asks students to collect data about what do
their friends like     to do after school and make a table from
this data. Does not     tell students how to make a pie chart. \\
12&165&NA&Yes&NA&Bar Graph&Bar graph showing temperature of 4
cities in     Summer and Winter. Questions to be answered by
studying these     graphs. The Y-axis has temperature in degree
Centigrade,     while X-axis has cities.&Data directly in the bar
graph, not shown     in form of table. No Source given. &A good
introduction to     bar graphs, but students are not told how to
make such a     chart. The follow up activity asks students to
collect data about     temperature of cities from newspapers or
television and     make a bar chart. The students are to ask
questions based on     the charts they draw to their peers. Also
students are     encouraged to relate the temperatures to
geographical location     of the cities. \\
12&168&NA&NA&NA&Line Graph&Line / point graph showing length of plant
in terms of days. The points are plotted  from a table given for the
data. The X-axis has number of days, and Y-axis has length of plant in
centimeters.&Data of growth of plant as a function of days given in
form of a table. The data is from observing of plants of moong
seeds. &Students are supposed to draw similar graph and check if their
graph matches the one in the textbook. Investigative questions to be
answered based on the graph. \\
\bottomrule

\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\advance\vsize6cm
\csname @colroom\endcsname=\vsize
\textheight=\vsize
\csname @colht\endcsname=\vsize
\small
     \begin{longtable}{@{}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{5cm}p{4cm}p{5cm}}
\caption{Survey data from a  Mathematics textbook.}
\label{tba-math-5}\\

\hline
\textbf{Chapter}&\textbf{Page}&\textbf{Figure
  No.}&\textbf{Caption}&\textbf{Legend}&\textbf{Graph}&\textbf{Description}&\textbf{Data} &\textbf{Comments}\\

\hline

\endfirsthead
\hline

\textbf{Chapter}&\textbf{Page}&\textbf{Figure No.}&\textbf{Caption}&  \textbf{Legend}&\textbf{Graph}&\textbf{Description}&\textbf{Data}    &\textbf{Comments} \\

\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{9}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot

12&159&NA&NA&Yes&Bar Graph&Bar graph in a primitive form, tally
used for     counting and also as a legend. Investigative
questions to be answered     by looking at the chart.&Number of
different     favourite pet animals of children in form of a
table.&This is a good     introduction to bar charts, where number
count in form     of tally marks is used for counting and hence as
a measure of     height of a particular variable. \\
12&161&NA&NA&Yes&Bar Graph&Bar graph in a primitive form, tally
used for     counting and also as a legend. Investigative
questions to be answered     by looking at the chart.&Number of
different     vehicles passing a street in form of a table.&Follow
up from the     previous task. Here also number count in form of
tally marks is used for counting and hence as a measure of height
of a particular variable. The     follow up task asks students to
collect data about     trees in their colony and make a tally-bar
chart for the     data. \\
12&163&NA&NA&Yes&Pie Chart&Pie chart introduced as a Chapati chart
and     numbers to be matched on pie chart from table. It also
asks them investigative questions to be answered using such a
chart.&Number of children who     help most in house work in form
of     table.&This activity introduces students to pie charts. The
follow up task     asks students to collect data about what do
their friends like     to do after school and make a table from
this data. Does not     tell students how to make a pie chart. \\
12&165&NA&Yes&NA&Bar Graph&Bar graph showing temperature of 4
cities in     Summer and Winter. Questions to be answered by
studying these     graphs. The Y-axis has temperature in degree
Centigrade,     while X-axis has cities.&Data directly in the bar
graph, not shown     in form of table. No Source given. &A good
introduction to     bar graphs, but students are not told how to
make such a     chart. The follow up activity asks students to
collect data about     temperature of cities from newspapers or
television and     make a bar chart. The students are to ask
questions based on     the charts they draw to their peers. Also
students are     encouraged to relate the temperatures to
geographical location     of the cities. \\
12&168&NA&NA&NA&Line Graph&Line / point graph showing length of plant
in terms of days. The points are plotted  from a table given for the
data. The X-axis has number of days, and Y-axis has length of plant in
centimeters.&Data of growth of plant as a function of days given in
form of a table. The data is from observing of plants of moong
seeds. &Students are supposed to draw similar graph and check if their
graph matches the one in the textbook. Investigative questions to be
answered based on the graph. \\
\bottomrule

\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```